# How can I erase cookie

Tags: node.js, backend, setcookie

I am creating backend for my website. There is one cookie named login whose value set when I login. I want that when I click on logout, the cookie should be erased

Here is what I wrote for logout function

```
res.cookie('login',' ',{maxage:1})
res.statuscode=301
res.setHeader("Location","http://localhost:3000")
res.end()
```

When I click on logout, i got directed to localhost:3000 but cookie do not get deleted.
I used cookie-parser package in nodejs

Comment: You can’t clear a cookie for another origin

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a simple HTTP server and are doing other things right, setting the cookie expiry to any past date will delete the cookie.

```
const setCookieHeader = 'myCookieName=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;';
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', setCookieHeader);
```

To redirect from the server side use the Location header the following the code

```
res.writeHead(302, { Location: 'https://google.com' });
```

Comment: After deleting cookie I want to redirect client